# wpf custom cursor in XAML?

Tags: wpf, cursor

I read quite a few SO links and the 1000-page "Programming WPF" and things are not so working.

I have this in MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Cursor x:Key="rightArrowCursor">Resources/im_pane</Cursor>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Setter Property="Cursor"  Value="{StaticResource rightArrowCursor}"/>
    </Style>
```

and `im_pane.cur` is added as existing file to Resources.

When the mouse is over `DataGridRowHeader`, I get exception:

> XamlParseException: Failed to create a 'Cursor' from the text
>   'Resources/im_pane' ... Requested value 'Resources/im_pane' was not
>   found.

I also tried `Properties/Resource/im_pane`, or `im_pane.cur`, still got the same error.

I just wonder how you use custom cursor in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned in 
http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/wpf-loading-grab-and-grabbing-cursors-from-resource/

we can not directly define cursor in resourcedictionary you need to use dummy textblock and then need to use that cursor.